# GTK and Cairo Drawing handles

Tags: c#, resize, cairo, gtk#

so for my purposes I was hoping to create a rudimentry app to handle the drawing and reshaping of engineering diagrams, simply as a project to teach me some means of building applications. however, I am unsure of how to get event handling from a line/ shape that has already been drawn.

for example if i draw a circle can i use the event handling from glib to then potentially add handles in the corners of a bounding box to be able to resize the circle.

for example in psudo code can i write my own object

```cs
class DrawCircle : ResizeHandleObject
{
    DrawCircle(xArg, yArg, rad)
    {
        cr.arc(xArg, yArg, rad, 0, 0);
    }

    [signal("clicked")]
    DisplayResizeHandles();

}
```

it's very possible that this is a simple problem but i just don't know any rescources that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Not as such, I don't believe. I think you will need to use the Cairo context to draw the handles yourself, and then use the button/motion/leave events on the widget (I assume you're using a DrawingArea??) to catch when the mouse cursor is positioned over a handle when a button is clicked, when/how the cursor then moves, and to redraw the circle (and the position of the handles) appropriately.